# Number of bits required after thresholding - DCT

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dct

For a question on an assignment I am required to implement image compression via thresholding in Discrete Cosine Transformation. I've converted my required greyscale image to a matrix of DCT co-efficients, and have thresholded values by setting co-efficients below a certain proportion of the maximum absolute co-efficient to 0.

Now I am also required to calculate the total number of bits after compression. Assuming that all co-efficients that have value 0 require 0 bits to represent, i.e, no overhead of RLE or whatever else, by my understanding the total number of bits should be **(number of non-zero co-efficients) x (size of variable)**, which is double in this case (in Matlab).

The issue is, if I set my threshold to be 1% of the max. value, I end up with 36,714 non-zero values in the thresholded matrix. Since doubles in Matlab are 64 bits, the number of bits required is 64*36714 = **2349696 bits**. Compare this with the original 512x512 greyscale image, which required 512*512*8 bits = **2097152 bits**. Thus **my "compressed" image is actually larger than the original one**!

Given that I can only use thresholding, and no quantisation of any sort, is this really the number of bits required with a threshold of 1%? Or is there a way to store doubles in Matlab without having to use 64 bits?

Comment: have you tried `single` precision variables?

Comment: @Shai, currently I use the `im2double` function for processing the image, since most Matlab image functions require the image to be a matrix of doubles. 

What would be the consequence of converting the final thresholded matrix of doubles to single? Would it lead to a significant loss in precision?

Comment: use `im2single` and get x2 "compression" for (almost) free